# Waypoints JS bottom-in-view, is there a top-in-view?

Tags: javascript, scroll, viewport, jquery-waypoints

Im using waypoints js to detect when an element is in the viewport.

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints

Is it possible to detect when the **top** of an element is at the bottom of the viewport?

Cheers

Ke

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nobody has given a *correct* answer yet, so here is mine.

As you already know, the Waypoint plugin has an `offset` option. This option triggers the handler function after either the top or bottom of your element has passed either the top or bottom of the viewport.

The offset value as a percentage represents the height of the viewport where you want the function to fire - 0% being right at the top, 50% in the middle, and 100% right at the bottom.

To fire your handler function when the top of your element immediately comes into view, you will need to use 100%, like this:

```
$('.sections').waypoint({
    handler: function(direction) {
        // do stuff
    },
    offset: '100%'
});
```

Comment: If an element starts in view, and you scroll down, then back up to it, it will never trigger again.